# What does move forward with frameworks mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/framework?q=framework

“To enable further digitalization, establishing single standards is a prerequisite, so this is a good initiative,” Andy Lane, port expert and partner at CTI Consultancy, told JOC.com. “It might require a separate or neutral entity to drive it, however, which might be an existing association such as [the International Association of Ports and Harbors] or a new entity. The primary challenge will always be reaching fast consensus and moving expeditiously forward with frameworks.”

Source: https://www.joc.com/port-news/european-ports/port-rotterdam/major-ports-begin-aligning-data-networks-cargosmart-tradelens_20200728.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'To move forward with frameworks' can be interpreted as:

To proceed and implement the single standards established by that entity.

Comment: A framework usually means how multiple standards (or regulations) work together toward a particular goal, not a single standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is (pretentious) jargon-laden prose that is written for those specialists in port management who have become uncritically used to this way of talking. Do not be impressed by it.

*The primary challenge will always be reaching fast consensus and moving expeditiously forward with frameworks.* = *It will first be important to agree on, and make arrangements for, running ports.*

Some explanation of *framework* may be found in https://ppiaf.org/sites/ppiaf.org/files/documents/toolkits/Portoolkit/Toolkit/module1/context.html